# How to get dataset information via the Python API

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get dataset information via the Python client libraries. In the BigQuery UI I can see the created date, data location etc are set, but when I try to get it via the API, it's just returning `None`. In the [documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.dataset.Dataset.html#google.cloud.bigquery.dataset.Dataset), it says "(None until set from the server)", but if I can see it on the UI, I assumed (presumably wrongly) that it was set.

Here's my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
dataset_ref = client.dataset('myDatasetName')
dataset_info = bigquery.dataset.Dataset(dataset_ref)
print(dataset_info.created)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there.

```
dataset_ref = client.dataset('myDatasetName')
dataset_info = client.get_dataset(dataset_ref)
print(dataset_info.created)
```